# Sanic CORS Exception handler

Tags: sanic, flask-cors

I have tried to use Sanic_CORS in exception handler like error 404,
but I received CORS error 
`Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://backend:port/endpoint' from origin 'http://react_app:port' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.`
There are no problems with valid endpoints.

My error handler

```
@app.exception(NotFound)
async def ignore_404s(request, exception):
    return response.json({'message': "Oops, server error"},
                          status=404)
```

How can I implement Sanic_CORS for error handlers? Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

One option would be to just add the header into your response. Albeit, this is not using the `sanic-cors` package, but you really do not need it here.

```py
@app.exception(NotFound)
async def ignore_404s(request, exception):
    return response.json(
        {'message': "Oops, server error"},
        status=404,
        headers={"Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"}
    )
```